# Change stroke drawing order (Arrange stroke)-Grease pencil

Tags: python, scripting, grease-pencil

Just curious, the default stroke draw order in greasepencil is bottom to top(i.e first stroke at the bottom,next stroke on top of it and so on ...).Can this order ebe reversed (i.e top to bottom)?
I know there is an "Arrange stroke" option which lets one change the draw order after drawing the stroke but an option to provide the above functionality would make drawing a whole lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

Checked - Draw on Back option (underneath Continuous drawing)